# 2009 Toyota Yaris Hathback - rear light change?

Tags: electrical, toyota, tail-lights, yaris

I'm trying to change the parking light on my 2009 Toyota Yaris Hatchback, and running into some trouble getting the panel off. Hoping somebody can help me out.

The following picture shows the enclosure (working driver side (left))
I've removed the 2 nuts, however, the tail light cover still won't come off. It appears held on by something in the lower left (facing from outside).

[image: Yaris light enclosure]

I noticed what appears to be a plastic "bolt" ? shown in the next picture ... not sure if that's what's holding it - but if it is, I have no idea how to remove it ?

[image: plastic nut?]

Any help would be appreciated.

[edit]
Forgot to mention, I'm trying to change the light bulb for parking light. The top light of the three lights.
[/edit]

[edit2]
trying to explain which light I'm trying to access ... 
[image: The light I need, is tucked up above, not visible in this picture]
[/edit2]

[edit3]
A better picture, showing the top parking light I need to change. (it's actually visible in my first picture as well, the one showing the 2 nuts I removed. I'ts just to the right of the top most nut).

[image]

Comment: Are you trying change a light bulb or the entire assembly?

Comment: Sorry, thought I mentioned that in there .. ;)  lol was so focused on getting the pictures .. forgot that part ... I'm trying to change the parking light. The top light of the three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the light assembly you remove the two bolts in your first picture. That white plastic thing in your second picture holds a metal stud that's threaded into the light assembly. You need to carefully pry it out while sliding the assembly towards the rear of the car.

Comment: FYI, I just uploaded an additional picture of the light I need to change. But ok, so that plastic "cap?" ... I can reach it with needle nose pliers, but that's about it ... I don't want to break it, so how forcefully do I work on it ? Does it screw off? or just "pull" off ?

Comment: @Ditto it'll pull out it should just be a ball and socket deal. If you hear cracking stop and reevaluate your prying point. As to your newest picture it looks like you can just twist the bulb socket out as is.

Comment: ok, thanks, based on the way the wires "folded", I didn't think it would come out this way .. but I'll give that a try, and maybe try pulling the plastic cap ... give me a min .. :)

Comment: Thank you .. that did the trick .. took a bit of work still .. that wire is short, and no slack .. but it "just" had enough room to slide out.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

To change the light bulb itself just simply grab the white connector and turn it to the left. The socket will then pop out. You will have access to the bulb.
When handling the light bulb use a  piece of kleenex as the acids from your fingertips will etch the glass and cause it to break with time. Removing the whole assembly is unnecessary.

Comment: which connector?  the main white connector shown in the 2nd picture is the turn signal .. but I need to change the bulb above that - which I can't really reach. From what I read/understood, I need to remove the full tail light assembly from the vehicle, so I can get to the light ?

Comment: Ok the cream colored one above that one....sorry .  The white and grey one below looks like the it a little pin to depress before pulling out.

Comment: But that's still not the light I want to change .. the parking light is hidden in the picture, tucked up underneath the metal frame. O.o  (sorry, I think I described the white connector as the turn signal, the white connector I think is just electrical connection to the entire assembly, the cream color one is the middle turn signal - see my third pic I added?)

Comment: Try this  https://youtu.be/dFR8AiAAdBc

Comment: I saw that video. At 30-35 he removes something from inside - I have no idea how he does that, since mine doesn't look anything like what he pulls out of it. O.o   Although yes, the inside trunk looks exactly like mine ... so I wasn't able to follow that .. :(

Comment: I'll try to get some better pics deeper in tomorow in better lighting ..